# golang sql.Tx Exec with single quotes - statement requires 0 parameters

Tags: go

I am using pq and I have a function like this:

```
func UpdateTable(tx *sql.Tx) error {
    _, err := tx.Exec(`
    copy public.mytable FROM
    's3://mybucket/mytable' credentials
    'aws_access_key_id=$1;aws_secret_access_key=$2' DELIMITER AS '|'
    GZIP ESCAPE;`,
        os.Getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
        os.Getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"))

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

When attempting to run the function, I receive the error

```
pq: got 2 parameters but the statement requires 0
```

Is this due to the raw string and single quotes in the SQL statement? Can I make this work with the string literal?

Comment: Have you tried using `?` instead of `$X`?

Comment: The placeholder for PostgreSQL is $X, but yes, I've even tried ?.

Comment: have you tried only with double quotes **"** **"** ?

Comment: `COPY` does not support query parameters, so you need to format the query manually before passing it to `Exec`.

Comment: I had the same problem with `("select * from table where name=?", name)`, `("select * from table where name='?'", name)`, `("select * from table where name='$'", name)`, `("select * from table where name='$1'", name)` but it has solved by => `("select * from person where name=$1", name)`.